# Segment dataframe every time a value repeats in Python using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying generate strings or atleast a different dataframe from a dataframe that I have. The one that I have is:

```
Line    MM/DD/YYhh:mm:ss.ms.us  TEST    
9   04/17/2013:44:18.215.500    S   
20  04/17/2013:44:18.216.020    U   
27  04/17/2013:44:18.216.544    P   
34  04/17/2013:44:18.217.064    P   
39  04/17/2013:44:18.217.584    L   
48  04/17/2013:44:18.218.104    Y   
55  04/17/2013:44:18.218.627    P   
62  04/17/2013:44:18.219.147    R   
69  04/17/2013:44:18.219.667    <CR>    
76  04/17/2013:44:18.220.187    <LF>    
179 04/17/2013:44:18.721.249    U   
184 04/17/2013:44:18.721.769    L   
193 04/17/2013:44:18.722.289    <CR>    
200 04/17/2013:44:18.722.812    <LF>    
304 04/17/2013:44:19.236.017    E   
311 04/17/2013:44:19.236.537    R   
318 04/17/2013:44:19.237.060    R   
327 04/17/2013:44:19.237.580    <CR>    
334 04/17/2013:44:19.238.100    <LF>    
371 04/17/2013:44:19.649.033    M   
376 04/17/2013:44:19.649.553    O   
383 04/17/2013:44:19.650.073    D   
390 04/17/2013:44:19.650.596    E   
395 04/17/2013:44:19.651.116    ?   
402 04/17/2013:44:19.651.636    <CR>    
409 04/17/2013:44:19.652.156    <LF>    
489 04/17/2013:44:20.160.040    T   
496 04/17/2013:44:20.160.560    P   
505 04/17/2013:44:20.161.084    <CR>    
512 04/17/2013:44:20.161.604    <LF>    
607 04/17/2013:44:20.642.301    P   
614 04/17/2013:44:20.642.821    R   
623 04/17/2013:44:20.643.345    <CR>    
630 04/17/2013:44:20.643.865    <LF>
```

I am trying to format the above snippet to strings such that it looks like this

```
04/17/2013:44:18.220.187-SUPPLYPR<CR><LF>
04/17/2013:44:18.722.812-UL<CR><LF>
.
.
.
```

What it should do is that It should take the MM/DD/YY data where the value of TEST is  and combine all the values in TEST upto each  and make a string for each occurrence of . The raw data that I used to get till this Dataframe was different and was lot of work. But now I am kinda stuck on how to get this format. Any ideas/suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Problem statement unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `groupby`:

```
(df.groupby(df.TEST.shift().eq('<LF>').cumsum())
   .agg({'MM/DD/YYhh:mm:ss.ms.us':'last',
         'TEST':''.join})
   .reset_index(drop=True) 
)
```

Output:

```
     MM/DD/YYhh:mm:ss.ms.us              TEST
0  04/17/2013:44:18.220.187  SUPPLYPR<CR><LF>
1  04/17/2013:44:18.722.812        UL<CR><LF>
2  04/17/2013:44:19.238.100       ERR<CR><LF>
3  04/17/2013:44:19.652.156     MODE?<CR><LF>
4  04/17/2013:44:20.161.604        TP<CR><LF>
5  04/17/2013:44:20.643.865        PR<CR><LF>
```

Comment: Wow. This worked perfectly!! Thank you so much!! One more thing, What if I wanted to add the 'Line' column to this or a text (eg- 'cool') on the left most side?

Comment: chain that with `assign(Line=your_new_values)`. But then you need to rearrange the columns manually for the new column to be on the left most.

Comment: What about the already present 'Line' column from the snippet above?

Comment: What do you want to do with it, you can do, for example `.agg({'Line':'first', 'MM/DD...`